# Keeping data object after filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

**Small Background intro**

I´m currently working the User Administration page of my project and running into a small problem here. I have a table which contains some material-ui`s Usercard. For Each user that uses my System exist´s one card. The card´s are generated from data that comes from my database and then written into a *redux store*.

The Admin can do several interactions with the database that changes some Userdata. To provide an easy way to find a specific user a `<TextField />` was implemented that filter´s the table of Usercards.

*All of the things mentioned here works!*

**The Problem**

As mentioned in the Intro the data are stored in a *redux store*. When I filter the data, an action is dispatched

```
    export const FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME = "FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME"
    export const FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT = "FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT"

    export default function filterAllUser(filter, filterOption){
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            if(filterOption === 'name'){
                return dispatch (filterUserByName(filter))
            }else{
                return dispatch (filteUserByDepartment(filter))
            }
        }
    }

    function filterUserByName(filter){
        return {
            type: FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME,
            filter: filter
        }
    }

    function filteUserByDepartment(filter){
        return {
            type: FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT,
            filter: filter
        }
    }
```

*The Reducer*

Even if the reducers works, it is the **main reason for my problem**.

*Why?*

It is because, when I filter the data I was not able to *really filter the state, rather then return a new state object which leads me to the problem that the `allUserData` and `filteredUserData` get out of sync after the userdata are changed*.

Let me explain this in code

```
    function allUser(state = {allUserData: []}, action){
        switch (action.type){
            case 'REQUEST_ALL_USER':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: true
                });
            case 'RECEIVE_ALL_USER':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    allUserData: action.items
                });
            case 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    filteredUserData: state.allUserData.filter(user => user.userNameLast.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                });
            case 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    filteredUserData: state.allUserData.filter(user => user.departmentName.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                });
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

But when I´m trying to filter the original state and the user removes the filter, the data that didn´t matched the filter are gone.

```
    case 'FILTER_ALL_USERS': return allUsers.filter(user => user.userNameLast.toLowerCase().indexOf(action.filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
```

How can I filter the state, but **keep the data** ?

Comment: Why not also store the filter and filteredUsers in the state, and any time you get an update on filter or data, update filteredUsers too?

Comment: This could work, but it sounds for me like an unclean solution of this problem.

Comment: The only other option is to store filter in the state and every time you need the filtered users, you filter it on the fly manually or by using something like reselect.

Comment: could you express your first comment in code probably?

Comment: Code added below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I have put together some code for you. It would be something like below.

As a side note, I would pass the filter as { field: 'userLastName', text: `your filter text`} as the filter criteria. Or to make it even more scalable, you can pass a filter-handler instead of text above. That way you can have any type of filter, and not just text filters.

```
export default function allUser(state = {allUserData: [], filters: {}, filteredUserData: []}, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case 'REQUEST_ALL_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case 'RECEIVE_ALL_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        allUserData: action.items,
        filteredUserData: filterData(action.items, state.filters),
      };
    case 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME':
    {
      const updatedFilters = {
        ...state.filters,
        userNameLast: action.filter
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUserData: filterData(state.allUserData, updatedFilters),
        filters: updatedFilters
      };
    }
    case 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT':
    {
      const updatedFilters = {
        ...state.filters,
        departmentName: action.filter
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUserData: filterData(state.allUserData, updatedFilters),
        filters: updatedFilters
      };
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const filterData = (users, filters) => {
  return users.filter(filterFn(filters));
};

const filterFn = filters => item => Object.keys(filters).reduce((res, filter) => {
  return res && item[filter].toLowerCase().indexOf(filters[filter].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}, true);
```

Unit tests

```
import usersReducer from './users';

describe('usersReducer', () => {
  describe('RECEIVE_ALL_USER', () => {
    const RECEIVE_ALL_USER = 'RECEIVE_ALL_USER';
    it('should replace users in state', () => {
      const initialState = { isFetching: false, allUserData: [{ name: 'A' }], filters: {}};
      const newUsers = [{ name: 'B' }];
      const newState = { ...initialState, allUserData: newUsers, filteredUserData: newUsers};
      expect(usersReducer(initialState, { type: RECEIVE_ALL_USER, items: newUsers })).toEqual(newState);
    })
  })
  describe('FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME', () => {
    let FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME = 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME';
    it('should filter users by name', () => {
      const initialState = { isFetching: false, allUserData: [{ userNameLast: 'Doe' }, { userNameLast: 'Smith' }], filters: {}};
      const filterText = 'd';
      const finalState = { isFetching: false,
        allUserData: [{ userNameLast: 'Doe' }, { userNameLast: 'Smith' }],
        filters: { userNameLast: filterText },
        filteredUserData: [{ userNameLast: 'Doe' }]
      };

      expect(usersReducer(initialState, { type: FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_NAME, filter: filterText})).toEqual(finalState);
    })
  })
  describe('FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT', () => {
    let FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT = 'FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT';
    it('should filter users by department', () => {
      const initialState = { isFetching: false, allUserData: [{ departmentName: 'IT' }, { departmentName: 'Human Resources' }], filters: {}};
      const filterText = 'it';
      const finalState = {
        ...initialState,
        filters: { departmentName: filterText },
        filteredUserData: [{ departmentName: 'IT' }]
      };

      expect(usersReducer(initialState, { type: FILTER_ALL_USER_BY_DEPARTMENT, filter: filterText})).toEqual(finalState);
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Awesome work buddy. Thank you very much for your help! I have just replaced my old reducer with this one, and without any changes it works!

Comment: If interested, I can also paste the tests I written for these. They are basic tests and don't cover edge cases, but they work!!

Comment: yeah would love to see them!

Comment: Unit tests added. But as I said, they are just basic tests and doesn't cover all cases, so if you want to use them, you will need to write more tests.

Answer (score 1):

Best for these cases is to some selector library, example [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). Instead of editing the original state create selectors for sorting and filter and pass the result to component.

There's also a quite similar example in reselect documentation https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#selectorstodoselectorsjs.